# WPF ImageBrush Transform from codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

In XAML I have this:

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="TE_Tex_001"
    ImageSource="d:\exterior.bmp"
    ViewportUnits="Absolute"
    Transform="1,0,0,-1,0,1"
    TileMode="Tile" />
```

In codebehind I want to create this same ImageBrush- and I seem to be all good with everything except the Transform property.  According to docs this is a System.Windows.Media.Transform, and can be any of the scale rotate or translate transforms.

But I can't find any of them that would take "1,0,0,-1,0,1" as arguments, properties or anything.  I thought it might be move from 1,0,0 to -1,0,1 but that doesn't seem possible with translate translate transform.

So what kind of transform is "1,0,0,-1,0,1", and how do I set it in codebehind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `MatrixTransform`.

```
TE_Tex_001.Transform = new MatrixTransform(1.0d, 0.0d, 0.0d, -1.0d, 0.0d, 1.0d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx) to see what those six numbers mean.